# permissions required to copy S3 file through console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I am trying to rename an object in S3 through the AWS Console.

I have a role to which I attached two policies.

A "read" permission

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bfe-dp-test3-pos-lz",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bfe-dp-test3-pos-lz/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And a "write" set of permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:PutBucketLogging",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:RestoreObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bfe-dp-test3-pos-lz",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bfe-dp-test3-pos-lz/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Yet, when I try to rename a file (object) through the AWS Console, I get a failed error message without details...

Any idea which additional permission might be missing?

Comment: You said attached to the role, have you attached the permissions to your IAM user?

Comment: Yes but it looks like my problem was due to encryption...

Comment: Right so your objects were encrypted?

Comment: yes... Just did not think about this detail...

Comment: I am getting "better" but AWS is still a black art to me!

Comment: Thats fine, its all experiences. Always worth checking KMS configuration for services nowadays. Its very easy in some services to enable it :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to **replicate the issue** with my own bucket and I found no issues with your two policies.

My verification process:

1. Create two **managed policies**: one `read` and one `write` as you described.
2. Create an **IAM role** containing the two policies. The trust policy was my sandbox account `arn:aws:iam::xxxx:root`
3. Use console to **Switch Role** in order to **assume the role** created in step 2.
4. While being in the assumed role, I tried **renaming** an object in the bucket and found no issues. I also could upload objects to the bucket.

Thus it seems to me that there is something else happening. Maybe you have something wrong with other policies in the role? Or bucket has some policies deny some actions? Are as explained in the comments, extra **KMS** permissions are required for the role if the objects are encrypted.

Comment: I need to double check but it would appear my problem was due to encryption on the buckets.

I need to add 
            {
                "Sid": "kmsAccess",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "kms:List*",
                    "kms:*"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            },

Comment: @EricMamet Makes sense. I will update the question to add KMS under " something else happening" :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case above, I was missing access to Encryption!

Had to add this to my "read" policy

```
            {
                "Sid": "kmsAccess",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "kms:List*",
                    "kms:*"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            },
```

Thanks for your help