# S3 policy to perform move action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Which permission needed to perform move action on objects within the same S3 bucket?

To clarify, we have a bucket named `BCK` and two folders inside named `DIR1` & `DIR2`. An IAM user needs to move objects within `DIR1` to `DIR2` and when they perform the action from the management console management they get the an error "access denied".

The only policy attached to the user is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BCK/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BCK"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are the objects possibly encrypted with KMS? [amazon web services - permissions required to copy S3 file through console? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755606/permissions-required-to-copy-s3-file-through-console) Did you check CloudTrail to see whether there is more information available in the failed API call?

Comment: we don't configure cloudtrail to cach API calls and object are not server side encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "move" command in Amazon S3. Instead, it requires a combination of `CopyObject` and `DeleteObject`. You have already provided these permissions.

The Amazon S3 management console also performs additional steps during the copy operation, such as viewing/setting permissions on each object. Therefore, add these permissions:

- `s3:GetObjectAcl`
- `s3:PutObjectAcl`

Comment: Thanks John, I added these permissions to the policy and that solve my problem.